# Opinion based questions-did not receive enough help

Tags: discussion

(hopefully this is the right place to ask)

I am asking this question because I am a bit concerned that questions are often not competently flagged, and users don't get support they need.

My question was tagged opinion based.
But here is the problem: I have completely no answer to this question.
**So, if someone had given me even *some* answer, that would already help me a lot.**
But it was just marked opinion based:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245076/skills-needed-for-kinect-development

Besides, as "opinion based" is concerned, I don't think this is opinion based, because there can be simple answer like you need to know basic physics for it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I closed the question as opinion based, as everyone will have a different opinion as to **what is required**.

I might think that simply knowing a C like programming language is enough.

Someone else may think C# is needed. A third person may think basic physics is required.

It is not possible to tell, because "kinect development" is vague. What kind of kinect development? A game? A security system? Something else?

Even if it were clearer, opinions would still be prevalent - this is simply not something that can be objectively answered.

---

You also seem to believe that the goal of our sites is to provide help to individuals.

It isn't.

We are trying to build a corpus of good questions and good answers that are fact based and are useful to many people.

Comment: @Odded: OK then for some strange reasons this question was not closed right? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/111558/what-should-i-know-before-getting-involved-in-kinect-development
Just the answers were not fully satisfactory to me and I added multitouch aspect

Comment: Plus like I said, it would be nice to have site which helped users in the sense that: like in my case, even *some* answer would be useful for me, since like I said currently, I completely have no answer for this. And I think any person experienced in Kinect development could have given a reasonable answer to my question

Comment: Well, that's a very old question, from times before standards here settled down, and yes, it **should** and **will** be closed now. I understand your frustration, however, the goals are not to be the place for any and every possible question - only a specific subset.

Comment: sad ... sad ...

Comment: For a bit of history of the site and why we crack down on some types of questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes